# How to Autowire FeignClient into Test Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I've written a `FeignClient` and I would like to test that it works using a unit test. (For my case, integration tests is not the right approach for the current development stage).

In my test, the FeignClient is not initialized (`null`): I receive a `NullPointerException` while running the test.

**How can I successfully Autowire a `FeignClient`?**

*Feign client*:

```
package com.myapp.clients;

import com.myapp.model.StatusResponse;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@FeignClient(name="myClient", url="${feign.clients.my.url}")
public interface myClient {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/users/{userId}")
    StatusResponse getStatus(
            @RequestHeader(value = "Auth", required = true) String authorizationHeader,
            @RequestHeader(value = "my_tid", required = true) String tid,
            @PathVariable("userId") String userId);

}
```

*Tests*:

```
package com.myapp.clients;

import com.intuit.secfraudshared.step.broker.model.StatusResponse;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class MyClientTest {

    @Autowired
    MyClient myClient;
    
    @Test
    public void testmyClient_status200() {

        StatusResponse myResponse = myClient.getStatus("", "tidTestSample", "4626745161770145");
        Assert.assertNotNull(iusResponse);
    }
}
```

**How can Autowire MyClient?**

Answer (score 3):

The method that has worked for me so far while trying to test Feign Clients is stubbing the response via wiremock. You would need to add dependency for wiremock.

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock'
```

Then you would need to annotate as

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "feign.clients.my.url=http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}")
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
```

And then stub using wiremock.

```
stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/v1/users/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)")).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200).withHeader("content-type", "application/json").withBody("{\"code\":200,\"status\":\"success\"})));
```

where `([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)` is regex for {userId} assuming it is alphanumeric.

And then, of course, assert.

```
StatusResponse myResponse = myClient.getStatus("", "tidTestSample", "4626745161770145");
Assert.assertNotNull(myResponse);
```

Comment: But `myClient` is null. How will it work

Comment: Did you autowire it?

Comment: I was using `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension)` which did not work so changed the code to use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. Then it worked fine.

Comment: Useful info, but doesn't answer the question, which was "How can autowire MyClient?"

Comment: @Doradus Normal `@Autowire` annotation should work.

Comment: The original question used `@Autowired` and did not work.

Comment: If you use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` on your test, autowire should work. The client will not be null, and we're anyway stubbing the response for the methods.

Comment: Does anyone have suggestions on how to get this to work with `Spock`/`Groovy` testing?